# Is there any way to check rtp stream coming from source over udp?

Tags: udp, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I've implemented the code to get video stream from camera source over **UDP**. I need to check whether the source (camera) sending data or alive. Is there any way to check in using `Gstreamer` or other way which is related socket programming?

In Gstreamer, there are several useful listeners to check pipline state. One of them is *end-of-stream* notification but it is not working to check udp source pipeline state.

From DOC:

> *End-of-stream notification: this is emitted when the stream has
> ended. The state of the pipeline will not change, but further media
> handling will stall. Applications can use this to skip to the next
> song in their playlist. After end-of-stream, it is also possible to
> seek back in the stream. Playback will then continue automatically.
> This message has no specific arguments.*

```
    Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline("monitoring-pipe");

    pipeline.getBus().connect((Bus.ERROR) this);
    pipeline.getBus().connect((Bus.WARNING) this);
    pipeline.getBus().connect((Bus.STATE_CHANGED) this);
    pipeline.getBus().connect((Bus.EOS) this);

    Element udpsrc = ElementFactory.make("udpsrc", "udpsrc");
    udpsrc.set("port", monitoringPort);

    vc.getElement().set("sync", false);

    udpsrc.setCaps(Caps
            .fromString("application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)101"));

    Bin bin = Gst.parseBinFromDescription(
            "rtph264depay ! video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream, profile=high ! h264parse ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! queue2 ! videoconvert",
            true);

    pipeline.addMany(udpsrc, bin, vc.getElement());
    Element.linkMany(udpsrc, bin, vc.getElement());

    pipeline.play();
    pipeline.setState(State.PLAYING);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> The watchdog element watches buffers and events flowing through a
> pipeline. If no buffers are seen for a configurable amount of time, a
> error message is sent to the bus.
>
> To use this element, insert it into a pipeline as you would an
> identity element. Once activated, any pause in the flow of buffers
> through the element will cause an element error. The maximum allowed
> pause is determined by the timeout property.
>
> This element is currently intended for transcoding pipelines, although
> may be useful in other contexts.

`watchdog` element could be used to detect an error on stream. `Bus.MESSAGE` listener catch if the server side streaming dead or closed. Unfortunately it is triggered only when stream is closed. It won't be triggered when stream starts again but still it can be utilized with  few changes (trigger another listener in that)

*here is the code which has few changes*:

```
Bin bin = Gst.parseBinFromDescription(
            "watchdog ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream, 
            profile=high ! h264parse ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! queue2 ! videoconvert",
            true);


pipeline.getBus().connect((Bus.MESSAGE) this);



@Override
public void busMessage(Bus bus, Message message) {
    if (message.getType().equals(MessageType.ERROR)) {
        //here you can get when stream has stopped 
        //and trigger another listener like 
        //state change listener to check or establish connection

        pipeline.setState(State.PAUSED);
        pipeline.setState(State.PLAYING);
    }
}
```